# How do I turn the n-ahead ARIMA predictions to undifferenced values?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, differencing

I`m doing a Monthly sales forecast based on some historical data. My question is when I do the Arima(p,d,q) and then I do forecast(arima_model) in order to get the fitted values, which are nicely following the historical data points, then If I take the mean values from the forecast func, which are the n-ahead predictions, they are negative and differenced, because I do d=2 for the Arima. Is there any chance to obtain a normal values for the means from the forecast function? My aim is to know the real sales for n-ahead periods. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here is what you can do with first-order differencing: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579328. With second-order differencing, you need to take another sum on top of of the first one.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for the hints! I`ve already passed by this thread, but I`m not sure if it works good, because my forecasted arima values are n-ahead, so they don`t have any "undifferenced data" behind. If my data is from 50 points, the forecasted values are from 50th to 55th point. If you see what I mean by that.

Comment: If you do not have the starting level (undifferenced) at time 50 and the starting difference (1st difference) at time 51, then I think it is impossible to predict the level from purely 2nd differences between 50 and 55.

Comment: @RichardHardy well If we target the fitted values of the ARIMA model which are on the differenced data, then it`s possible to undifference them because behind them we have the undiff data. But here I`m asking about the 51-55th forecasted n-ahead values which don`t have any normal values behind. Ok thank you!